# Swift TextField not receiving data

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

The 3rd Int (Numberofdemoters) does not contain any value when I look in the debugger.  The first 2 are receiving data.

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var Numberofpromoters = p.text.toInt()!
    var Numberofneutral = n.text.toInt()!
    var Numberofdemoters = d.text.toInt()!   
}
```

If I change the code and put Numberofpromoters to be the last assignation, it become the one not receiving any data and contains 0.

I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Anyone?

Comment: Check your p, n, and d outlets to make sure they are not nil. Usually code that doesn't work right with outlets is the result of a broken IBOutlet link. (BTW, I would expect the code above to require an unwrap on your outlets, like `p!.text.toInt()!` or `p?.text.toInt()!`)

Answer (score 0):

Either look at p, n and d in the debugger or put a println() statement showing their values.

Is using println() forget the toInt(): 
    println("p: \(p.text) n: \(n.text)  d: \(d.text) ")

Your problem has nothing to do with position unless it is causing some type of reload.